# Python: list of lists: replacing inner-lists with multiple/modified inner-lists

Tags: python, list

Consider the general case of the following list:

```
l = [['path/to/file', 0], ['path/to/folder$IDX/', 2], ['and/another/', 5]]
```

Meaning, a list of lists, where each list has a string on its first element that may or may not contain a special marker (in the example above it's `$IDX`) and some random integer on its second element.
My goal is to have a new list of lists, where every inner-list that has the special marker in its first element, will be replaced with X new lists, having X = 0, 1, 2..., n (where n is known) in place of the special marker.

For example, if n = 2, for the input above, the output should be:

```
l = [['path/to/file', 0], ['path/to/folder0/', 2], ['path/to/folder1/', 2], ['path/to/folder2/', 2], ['and/another/', 5]]
```

another example (again, for n = 2):
input:

```
l = [['random_text$IDX', 512], ['string', 2], ['more_$IDX_random_text', 5]]
```

output:

```
l = [['random_text0', 512], ['random_text1', 512], ['random_text2', 512], ['string', 2], ['more_0_random_text', 5], ['more_1_random_text', 5], ['more_2_random_text', 5]]
```

My first thought was dividing the original list to two list of lists, one that has the marker (`l_with`) and a second that hasn't (`l_without`), then processing `l_with` and adding it to `l_without`, but this rather naive attempt failed right away at the start:

```
>>> l = [['path/to/file', 0], ['path/to/folder$IDX/', 2], ['and/another/', 5]]
>>> l_with = [e for e in l if '$IDX' in e[0]]
>>> l_without = [e for e in l if '$IDX' not in e[0]]
>>> l_new = l_without + [[e[0].replace('$IDX', str(i)), e[1]] for i in range(3) for e in l_with]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

In addition, even if the above **would** work, it's not that scalable... (consider a more general case: what if each inner-list has more than two elements? The only assumption I can make for now is that my (special-or-not) string will be the first element on each inner-list.)

What's a concise way of doing that? (scalable or not...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help.

```
res = []
l = [['path/to/file', 0], ['path/to/folder$IDX/', 2], ['and/another/', 5]]
n = 2
for i in l:
    if "$IDX" in i[0]:
        for j in range(0, n+1):
            res.append([i[0].replace("$IDX", str(j)) ] + i[1:])
    else:
        res.append(i)

print res
```

**Output:**

```
[['path/to/file', 0], ['path/to/folder0/', 2], ['path/to/folder1/', 2], ['path/to/folder2/', 2], ['and/another/', 5]]
```

Comment: You should change this line to `res.append( [ i[0].replace("$IDX", str(j)) ] + i[1:]) ` as OP suggested there can be multiple elements in the list

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan; You are correct, if the user has more than 2 element in his list, your snippet is what is required. Thanks